# Click all popup elements in list

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xunit

I have a list of the all elements on a page with a class name of popup, and I would like to open and close each element one at a time. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
IList<IWebElement> links = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("popup"));

for (int i = 0; i < links.Count; i++)
{                                               
     IWebElement welcomePopup = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//div[@id='Buttons']/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(),'" + links[i].Text + "')]")));
     PopupWindowFinder popupFinder = new PopupWindowFinder(driver);
     string welcomePopupHandle = popupFinder.Click(welcomePopup);

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(links[i].Text))
     driver.SwitchTo().Window(welcomePopupHandle);
     driver.FindElement(By.Id("cmdClose")).Click();                
}
```

This only opens and closes the first element; once the first element is closed I receive a `System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on the `IWebElement welcomePopup` line. How do I get it to go through each item in the list? I am very much a beginner, so let me know if I am missing something that is very obvious to you.

Comment: It looks like you're missing the braces around the last two lines under your if statement...

Comment: The thing is, Selenium creates **objects** representing those links. My guess it's, after the window loses focus those objects are unbound. Try counting the number of links and get the object inside the loop, so that you retrieve only the link you are about to visit each time. Another approach may be getting href attribute for all links and then visiting them. That depends on what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you can provide the actual page.

Anyhow, can you try this?

```
String parentWindow = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
IList<IWebElement> links = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("popup"));

for (int i = 0; i < links.Count; i++)
{                                               
     IWebElement welcomePopup = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//div[@id='Buttons']/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(),'" + links[i].Text + "')]")));
     PopupWindowFinder popupFinder = new PopupWindowFinder(driver);
     string welcomePopupHandle = popupFinder.Click(welcomePopup);

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(links[i].Text))
     driver.SwitchTo().Window(welcomePopupHandle);
     driver.FindElement(By.Id("cmdClose")).Click();  
     driver.SwitchTo().Window(parentWindow);              
}
```

First, you need to get the original window handle.

Switch to popup instance

Do your operations on the popup.

Here try to switch back to the original window using `driver.SwitchTo().Window(parentWindow);`

Hope it helps.